# List Azure table storage table metadata having only table name

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

How can I get metadata - like the table's property names - about a Azure Table Storage's table when I only have the table name to begin with? This is what I have so far:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List the tables in this storage account
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<string> ListAllTables()
    {
        var storageAccount = GetStorageAccount();

        // Create service client for credentialed access to the Table service.
        var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.ToString(),
            storageAccount.Credentials);

        return tableClient.ListTables();
    }

    IEnumerable<string> ListTableMetadata(tableName)
    {
        // Now, just how can I list all the table metadata?
    }

    void main()
    {
        foreach (var tableName in ListAllTables())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table: " + tableName);

            // List all the table metadata
            Console.WriteLine("Properties: " + ListTableMetadata(tableName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by table metadata? Do you mean entities in the table?

Comment: @GauravMantri The property names is what I'm interested in.

Comment: AFAIK, Azure Tables don't have metadata like Azure Blobs or Queues.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Storage Table service does not enforce any schema for tables. So, two entities in the same table may have different sets of properties. If you would like to query all entities without knowing their properties beforehand, I would recommend looking at [DynamicTableEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.dynamictableentity.aspx), which returns all properties of an entity as key-value pairs.